# Space expansion and change of electromagnetic radiation wavelenght

Tags: space-expansion, curvature, wavelength, aether, frame-dragging

The expansion of the universe acts to a photon ray equally as an expanded baloon on points drawn on it just increasing the distances between this differential photons so the integral photon looks like a spring that is stretched by force. The question is why then we think that photons do not have anything with space if we consider the possibility of space as a medium which vibrations are just these photons. If this question is hard to explain easely an auxiliary question is are we 100% sure that from the MM experiment no any possibilities are given for the existence of a so called aether? Why I am insisting on it?... Because the effect Frame dragging... Gravitational time dilation... And gravity curving a photon trajectory lead us to be more careful in insisting that the space can not in any case be a medium...

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear to me what is being asked. Are you wondering why cosmological redshift is not evidence for the luminiferous aether?